# In CMake, how do I check whether a string contains an integral number?

Tags: regex, cmake, numbers, idioms, string-parsing

I have a string in CMake which I got somehow, in a variable `MYVAR`. I want to check whether that string is an integral number - possibly with whitespace. I have an ugly way to do it:

```
string(REGEX MATCH "^[ \t\r\n]*[0-9]+[ \t\r\n]*$" MYVAR_PARSED "${MYVAR}")
if ("${MYVAR_PARSED}" STREQUAL "")
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Oh no!" )
endif()
# Now I can work with MYVAR as a number
```

is there a better way? Or - should I just wrap this in a function?

Note: I'm using the CMake regex syntax as documented [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html#regex-match).

Comment: "I have an ugly way to do it" - You name "ugly" a regex containing only simple `*`, `+` and `?`? What is a *non-ugly* regex in that case? A regex which matches an exact string? Or do you want to check a string **without** using a regex? Well, you could iterate over string characters and apply simple state-machine, but I don't think that given way is simpler then the regex. Not sure what do you want from us.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: Non-ugly would be: `if (IS_NUMBER "${MYVAR})` or something like that... also, not having to use auxiliary variable, even if I do use a regex.

Comment: "Non-ugly would be: `if (IS_NUMBER "${MYVAR})`" - Do you really expect CMake to have ready check for a type which is rarely used (decimal with exponent using `E`)? Before your question I don't even think about such representation. "also, not having to use auxiliary variable, even if I do use a regex." - What about `if(MYVAR MATCHES "<your-regex>")`? This is perfectly valid check in CMake.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: You make a valid point. SO, let's forget about the exponent. See edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Option 1: Exact match

> I want to check whether that string is an integral number - possibly with whitespace.

If this is the exact spec I need, then I would check it like so:

```
string(STRIP "${MYVAR}" MYVAR_PARSED)
if (NOT MYVAR_PARSED MATCHES "^[0-9]+$")
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Expected number, got '${MYVAR}'")
endif ()
```

This first removes whitespace from `MYVAR`, storing the result in `MYVAR_PARSED`. Then, it checks that `MYVAR_PARSED` is a non-empty sequence of digits and errors out if it is not.

I think doing this ad-hoc is fine, but if you want a function:

```
function(ensure_int VAR VALUE)
  string(STRIP "${VALUE}" parsed)
  if (NOT parsed MATCHES "^[0-9]+$")
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Expected number, got '${VALUE}'")
  endif()
  set(${VAR} "${parsed}" PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()

ensure_int(MYVAR_PARSED "${MYVAR}")
```

### Option 2: Looser match

However, the following solution might in some cases be more robust, depending on your requirements:

```
math(EXPR MYVAR_PARSED "${MYVAR}")
```

This will interpret the value of `MYVAR` as a simple mathematical expression over 64-bit signed C integers. It will interpret `0x`-prefixed numbers in hex. It recognizes most C arithmetic operators.

On the other hand, it might be too permissive: this solution will accept things like  `0 + 0x3`. It will also variously warn or error depending on how broken the expression is. However, this might not be an issue if you subsequently validate the *range* of the number or something. You could, for instance, check `if (MYVAR_PARSED LESS_EQUAL 0)` and then error out if so.

Documentation for the `math` command: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/math.html

Comment: The 1st solution is what I'm using, only stricter w.r.t. to whitespace, so doesn't really answer my question. The second solution - if I use it, I still need to check what happens to `EXPR`. I don't mind the over-permissiveness w.r.t. notation, but - this will accept non-integral numbers. And like I said, it's a multi-command solution. So, +1 for effort but -1 for poor solutions :-(

Comment: @einpoklum - I don't think the poor solutions are _my fault_. The CMake language isn't built to handle numbers outside of the `math` command and the `if` numeric comparisons (which are also very permissive w.r.t. numeric prefixes). I'll also add that `math()` doesn't handle floating point _at all_.

Comment: You are officially absolved of the solutions being poor :-) ... interesting about no floating-point in math; that makes it a little better. And with the function wrapping this - +1!